# .htaccess RewriteRule for two similar URLs not working as expected

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am having issues writing the .htaccess for Apache to rewrite a couple of URLs.

So, one of the cases is:

```
URL: http://localhost/openhoney/google/4/Laura%20Neiva
Rule: RewriteRule ^openhoney/google/([0-9])/(.*)$  /openhoney/showgoogletrend.php?t=$2&id=$1 [L]
Final: http://localhost/openhoney/showgoogletrend.php?t=Laura%20Neiva&id=4
```

The case above works properly, but if I try something similar it doesn't work as expected.

```
URL: http://localhost/openhoney/twitter/1489/Coutinho
Rule: RewriteRule ^openhoney/twitter/([0-9])/(.*)$  /openhoney/showtwittertrend.php?t=$2&id=$1 [L]
Final: http://localhost/openhoney/showtwittertrend.php?t=Coutinho&id=1489
```

In this last case the "Final" URL works properly, but when I use the "URL", It doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `([0-9])` will just match a single number, you can use `([0-9]+)` if you want to match one or more numbers, or `([0-9]{4})` if you want 4 numbers *(no more, no less)* such like this:

```
RewriteRule ^openhoney/twitter/([0-9]+)/(.*)$  /openhoney/showtwittertrend.php?t=$2&id=$1 [L]
```